# The time that it takes for a function to run

Tags: php

What is the best way for getting how long a function takes to run until finish and then storing that number in a variable in PHP ?

How I would think about doing this is get the time right before the function is executed and right after and then take the difference of the former from the latter, but I don't know how get the time in php.

Also, I am trying to get the units to be in tenths and hundredths of second (.42 seconds), hopefully the function takes less than a second to complete so if anyone can help me convert it to those units, i'd appreciate that.

Comment: must have been asked before.....?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php is that your answer

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can do that using [microtime()](http://php.net/microtime).

```
$start = microtime(true);
for ($x=0;$x<10000;$x++) {}
$end = microtime(true);
echo 'It took ' . ($end-$start) . ' seconds!';
```

Comment: Using microtime is better if available that using time in my example because many functions run in under 1 second.

Answer (score 2):

See "Example #1 Timing script execution with microtime()" in the documentation.

http://docs.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$time = time();
call_your_function();
$time = time()-$time;
echo "The function took $time seconds to run\n";
```