# My Sql Case Vs PHP if-else performance

Tags: php, mysql, performance

I stuck in a situation for using a conditional block statement:
So I want to know which give fast

> performance between **mysql case expression** and **if-else**
>   condition.

My expression as follows

1. Php condition block:

   ```
   $data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select action,state from my_table"));
   if($data['action']==2 && $data['state']==0){
   $state=1;
   }
   else{
   $state=0;
   }
   ```
2. MySql condition :

   ```
   $data=mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query("select case when action = 2 and state = 0 then 1 else 0 end as state"));
   $state =$data['state'];
   ```

I need a faster solution for it. So please tell me which is more recommended.

Comment: test your self, run each case and add this to get the time http://stackoverflow.com/questions/535020/tracking-the-script-execution-time-in-php#answer-9288945

Comment: What do you mean by "faster"? You are not *doing anything* with the data so there is nothing to speed up, at least not on the PHP-side. You may be able to to squeeze out some speed on the database-side, but I doubt it will be worth your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can do some benchmark tests yourself to see which one performs best for you. However, in most cases, one won't see any differences in performance between 2 alternatives you provide.

Other things you should consider is code readability and maintainability. It is considered best practice to separate concerns into pieces. So, if your if-else condition is about business process, it should be in PHP. Otherwise, you can put it in data (mysql)

Answer (score 0):

The PHP route will wind up being significantly faster. Regardless of how fast the MySQL engine can process the CASE statements internally, the API-overhead and resource usage will make the MySQL route definitively slower.

That being said there may be legitimate reasons to do the CASE in MySQL based on project design concerns.