# MySQL - SELECT - duration depending on the type of data returned

Tags: mysql

I have a simple table with approx. 7000 rows for which I run the exact same MySQL query 10,000 times. In the 3 examples below I only change the data I want returned. However, the time between the 3 types of queries varies far too much. I would have expected the last query returning a default value `"SELECT 1"` to be the fastest and the first `"SELECT *"` to be the laziest. That's because I was thinking that MySQL doesn't have to do much processing when it returns 1, and even the memory used would be much less than if it had to return the entire row and make it available with all the columns. But things are exactly the opposite.

4.5993759632111 sec.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 145109811 BETWEEN start AND end LIMIT 1
```

5.3308868408203 sec.

```
SELECT ID FROM mytable WHERE 145109811 BETWEEN start AND end LIMIT 1
```

7.7556929588318 sec.

```
SELECT 1 FROM mytable WHERE 145109811 BETWEEN start AND end LIMIT 1
```

MySQL version is: 5.7.40.

**Can someone explain to me what is going on?**

-- the source code used to measure performance --

```
<?php
    include('config.php');
   
    // https://stackoverflow.com/a/22885011/2947462
    class ExecutionTime {
         private $startTime;
         private $endTime;
         public function start(){
             $this->startTime = microtime(true);
         }
         public function stop(){
             $this->endTime = microtime(true);
         }
         public function text(){
             return ($this->endTime - $this->startTime) . " sec.";
         }
    }
    $query = "SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE 145109811 BETWEEN start AND end LIMIT 1;";

    $executionTime = new ExecutionTime();
    $executionTime->start();
    for($i=0; $i<10000; $i++){
        mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
    }
    $executionTime->stop();
    echo $executionTime->text();
```

> Keep in mind that the performance of a SQL query also depends on
> whatever else might be running on the database when you run your query

So I put all 3 queries into one script and measured the performance. 10000 queries of type `SELECT 1`, 10000 queries of type `SELECT *`, 10000 queries of type `SELECT ID`, with the following results after 3 consecutive runs:

```
10:19:58 - SELECT 1  - 7.3224468231201 sec.
10:20:03 - SELECT *  - 4.6961460113525 sec.
10:20:08 - SELECT ID - 4.4760630130768 sec.
10:20:28 - SELECT 1  - 7.4960129261017 sec.
10:20:32 - SELECT *  - 4.4980108737946 sec.
10:20:37 - SELECT ID - 4.4355578422546 sec.
10:21:00 - SELECT 1  - 8.0782158374786 sec.
10:21:04 - SELECT *  - 4.4764659404755 sec.
10:21:09 - SELECT ID - 4.273129940033 sec.
```

To avoid the database being in some unknown states on multiple runs, I changed the order of the 3 queries and repeated the above test. The order is now 10000 queries of type `SELECT *`, 10000 queries of type `SELECT ID`, 10000 queries of type `SELECT 1`, with the following results after 3 consecutive runs:

```
10:22:23 - SELECT *  - 6.5342800617218 sec.
10:22:28 - SELECT ID - 5.1359310150146 sec.
10:22:35 - SELECT 1  - 7.1028819084167 sec.
10:22:52 - SELECT *  - 4.8350520133972 sec.
10:22:57 - SELECT ID - 4.4192798137665 sec.
10:23:04 - SELECT 1  - 6.9962570667267 sec.
10:23:18 - SELECT *  - 5.2138640880585 sec.
10:23:22 - SELECT ID - 4.3040509223938 sec.
10:23:30 - SELECT 1  - 7.1998341083527 sec.
```

And the last sequence of queries in order 10000 queries of type `SELECT ID`, 10000 queries of type `SELECT 1`, 10000 queries of type `SELECT *`, with the following results after 3 consecutive runs:

```
10:24:05 - SELECT ID - 4.7385289669037 sec.
10:24:12 - SELECT 1  - 7.1701371669769 sec.
10:24:17 - SELECT *  - 4.5180490016937 sec.
10:24:33 - SELECT ID - 5.6322748661041 sec.
10:24:41 - SELECT 1  - 7.4376618862152 sec.
10:24:45 - SELECT *  - 4.4281830787659 sec.
10:25:00 - SELECT ID - 5.3789880275726 sec.
10:25:07 - SELECT 1  - 7.3066239356995 sec.
10:25:12 - SELECT *  - 4.5297379493713 sec.
```

**TOTAL RESULTS:**

```
SELECT *    39.03364301 sec.
SELECT ID   42.79380441 sec.
SELECT 1    66.11007166 sec.
```

Comment: The times are way too high. Don't you have an index on the columns START and END? Then the difference should be minimal too.

Comment: The index (whether it exists or not) affects the query in the same way because the queries are perfectly identical. The data returned is different, which inexplicably results in large performance differences. I did the tests many times, interspersed. The results were the same with small insignificant variations.

Comment: 10000 elements in one table -the result takes a few milli seconds! http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/218c7c/1

Comment: Keep in mind that the performance of a SQL query also depends on whatever else might be running on the database when you run your query.  A better approach here would be to plot the distribution of run times.  I'll bet most executions are within a narrow band.

Comment: The performance of a query in SQL depends on the amount of data the query has to look on (even if there is no result) and the amount of data that it has in the return.  In your 3 queries it looks exactly to the same data, and it returns exactly one row, so `SELECT 1` it doesn´t need to be faster than `SELECT *`. As @TimBiegeleisen says, you might be running some process in the system (or some other query on the DB) that makes your query slower or faster

Comment: Yes, `SELECT 1` it doesn´t need to be faster than `SELECT *`, but I cannot see the reason that `SELECT 1` is so much slower than `SELECT *`. I run multiple tests and added the results into my question.